# Replicate R cor() function in Tableau

Tags: r, correlation, tableau-api

Why is there no tutorial online about replicating R's basic cor() function in tableau. All I can find are tutorials to visualize correlations of values by dimension. I just want to see how all variables in my data are correlated to each other.

And thanks for the support @user1036719

Comment: I don't understand the downvote--it's a very valid question...AND I answered it myself

Comment: I also think this is a very valid question.  I upvoted your question, comment, and answer to show my support.

Answer (score 5):

All,

I have figured out the simplest way to solve my own problem. With the introduction of Tableau 9.0, you can load .RData files directly into Tableau. Here is how you go about it:

1) Simply save() your correlation matrix as an .RData file.
2) Connect Tableau to the .RData file
3) Put "Measure Names" in the Columns field & "Rownames" in the Rows field.
4) Set Marks from "Automatic" to "Square"
5) Drag "Measure Values" over the "Color" Marks category

Voila! You're done. With the new R integration this is so much simpler than any solution I have found online.

Comment: Awesome!!!. Much appreciated. Worked perfectly with latest R and Tableau in case anyone was wondering.